# "ObjectsGroup" error "Integer out of range"

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I found code to make [Powerpoint VBA Harvey balls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29863568/powerpoint-vba-harvey-balls)

I changed the last line to `CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("ObjectsGroup")` instead of `CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("ShapesCombine")`.

The first run of macro went fine, but when I run again (the first Harvey ball was on slide) I had the error

> *Shapes (unknow member): Integer out of range. [#]is not in the valid
> range of [#] to [#]*

on the line `Set oshpR = sld.Shapes.Range(Array(shp1.ZOrderPosition, shp2.ZOrderPosition))`

If the shapes combined into one - there is no error. It appears with the group set only. I need this shapes as the group set on one slide. There could be multiple sets on the slide.

I assume it could be a problem, because it can be a lot of other group sets (not Harvey balls) on the slide.

```vb
Sub Test2()
    Dim sld As Slide
    Dim shp1 As Shape
    Dim shp2 As Shape
    Dim oshpR As ShapeRange

    Set sld = Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide
    Set shp1 = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeOval, 300, 100, 50, 50)
    Set shp2 = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.AddShape(msoShapePie, 300, 100, 50, 50)
    Set oshpR = sld.Shapes.Range(Array(shp1.ZOrderPosition, shp2.ZOrderPosition))
    CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("ObjectsGroup") 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grouping via CommandBars.ExecuteMso requires that the shapes to be grouped be selected. Creating a shaperange doesn't implicitly select the shapes in the range.

Try this instead:

```
Sub Test2()
Dim sld As Slide
Dim shp1 As Shape
Dim shp2 As Shape
Dim oshpR As ShapeRange

Set sld = Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide
Set shp1 = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeOval, 300, 100, 50, 50)
Set shp2 = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.AddShape(msoShapePie, 300, 100, 50, 50)
'Set oshpR = sld.Shapes.Range(Array(shp1.ZOrderPosition, shp2.ZOrderPosition))
' msoTrue forces a new selection
shp1.Select msoTrue
' msoFalse adds the shape to the current selection
shp2.Select msoFalse
CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("ObjectsGroup")
End Sub
```

You could also just select the shaperange you've defined:

```
Set oshpR = sld.Shapes.Range(Array(shp1.ZOrderPosition, shp2.ZOrderPosition))
oshpR.Select msoTrue
CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("ObjectsGroup")
```

Comment: Thanks, Steve! The first code works perfect! 
But the 2nd has the same error as before, just for info. Don't know why.

Comment: @LenaKire Glad it's working (at least the one method). But I just tried the other again here and it works. Odd!